# Error in IOS Swift Version

Tags: ios, swift2, uigesturerecognizer

I have downloaded the slide demo of swift from the url https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift and after compiling its show errors as per the screen shot.
[image]

Comment: What Swift version are you using?

Comment: It's working fine with Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2

Comment: Update Xcode, yours is too old.

Comment: I am using xcode 7.2

Comment: Xcode 7.2 is Swift 2.1. Read the documentation: In the section Requirements you will see *If you are developing in the swift2.1, please use branch of swift2.1*, but better update Xcode as Eric already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The code is for Xcode 7.3 / Swift 2.2

As you're using an older Swift version (2.1) you need to download the appropriate branch.

The requirements are

> Requires Swift2.0 and iOS 8.0 and ARC.
>
> If you are developing in the swift1.1, please use branch of swift1.1.
>   If you are developing in the swift1.2, please use branch of swift1.2.
>   **If you are developing in the swift2.1, please use branch of swift2.1.**